# Datepicker format is getting changes when i open form in edit mode

Tags: c#, datepicker

I have set the datepicker format as "dd/MM/yy". so when I open the form for insert the data at that time its taking right value. but when I open a form in edit mode the datepicker automatically changes the format to "MM/dd/yy".

```
dt.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dt.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this piece of line that may help you.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(date from database).ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

Thanks,
Anvesh